# join two tables where foreign key is concatenation of a standard string with primary key

Tags: mysql, join

I have two sql tables, Table A and Table B. Table A's primary key is Column 1. Joining with table b , column 2. Values in column 2 is always concatenation of "00" and column 1. eg: column 1 = '9832' and column 2 = "009832". I need to join these two columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should join those tables using their Id's for efficiency and best practice. For sake of migrations you can use following joins.

```
Select A.*, B.Column2
From TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B ON concat('00',A.Column1) = B.Column2
```